# Preg_match string and put matches into an array

Tags: php, arrays, input, preg-match-all

i'm creating a photo sharing system with a particular photo temp verify.
Basically, on input file submit photos are loaded into a dir called "temp".

I change the name of file in a particular string like this `3_1383310890_1709373616.jpg`
where 3 is the **user_id** 1383310890 is the **date** and 1709373616 is a random code name.

Now, if user doesn't complete the form... the next time, it should checks if exist a file temp for that user id and i would get info like this way but I do not understand why it does not work.

```
$string = 'temp/3_1383310890_1709373616.jpg';

    preg_match_all('/^[0-9]+_/',$string,$match);

    $arr = array('user' => $match[1][0], 'date' => $match[2][0], 'photo' => $match[3][0]);
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

it returns null objects

```
{"user":null,"date":null,"photo":null}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($match)`? What's in there?

Comment: i think that the real problem is into preg_match_all, what are you think about it?

Comment: What are you trying to match with this regex?  You are currently searching for "start of the string, followed by one or more digits, followed by an underscore".  The start of the string is "temp", which doesn't match "one or more digits".

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get you to find out - does your regex match what you think it's matching? If not, what does it match?

Comment: Damn, I'm so tired that I did not realize that i passed not correct string :D thanks anyway guys

Answer (score 0):

The ^ char. in this case means matching from the start of the string. I would use:

```
$string = 'temp/3_1383310890_1709373616.jpg';
preg_match('/^temp\/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)\.jpg$/',$string,$match);
$arr = array('user' => $match[0], 'date' => $match[1], 'photo' => $match[2]);
echo json_encode($arr);
```